# Bizarre output in random word generator

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, stdio

I am facing some problems with the output of the following program. The program randomly generate words, first a random consonant then a random vowel, and then the same again for the maximum number of letters you want.

When I print the word generated right after it is generated it gives me a list of words, as intended. When I am out of the word generating and stacking loop, and print an output of the words again, I get all the words mashed up in one long chain, it is really bizarre. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXWORDS 10
#define MAXLETTERS 6

int lcg(int Xcur)       /*linear congruential generator*/
{
    int A = 445, C = 700001, M = 2097152;
    int Xnext = (A * Xcur + C) % M;
    return Xnext;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    printf("input seed for linear congruential generator: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    char consonants[]="bcdfghjklmnprstvwxz";
    char vowels[]="aeiou";

    int i,j;
    int turn;

    char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS];

    for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS;i++)
    {
        turn=1;

        for(j=0;j<MAXLETTERS;j++,turn++)
        {
            x=lcg(x);           /* random number generated */

            if(turn%2)          /* one consonant, one vowel, in turn */
                words[i][j]=consonants[x%19];
            else
                words[i][j]=vowels[x%5];
        }

        words[i][j]='\0';

        /* print each word generated */
        printf("word %d: %s\n", i+1, words[i]);
    }

    /* print the first word again */
    printf("\n\nthe 1st word again: %s\n",words[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
input seed for linear congruential generator: 23
word 1: wuduca
word 2: navozo
word 3: depiza
word 4: jukiti
word 5: raliwi
word 6: danila
word 7: cexewi
word 8: bamohu
word 9: jiruzi
word 10: temomo


the 1st word again: wuducanavozodepizajukitiraliwidanilacexewibamohujiruzitemomo
```

Comment: Please add expected and actual outputs.

Comment: yeah sorry, done.

Comment: There is no room in the array for the string terminator. Try changing `char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS];` to `char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS+1];`

Comment: Alright! of course! thank you

Comment: @WeatherVane You should post that as the answer. Unless someone can be bothered to dig up an appropriate missing null terminator dupe.

Answer (score 4):

It is because is is getting stored in continuous manner without any null char.

Method 1:
If you just want to print it properly you can do it by writing below line:

```
printf("\n\nthe 1st word again: %s\n",words[0]);
```

as

```
printf("\n\nthe 1st word again: %.*s\n",MAXLETTERS, words[0]);
```

Method 2:

Declare words as

```
char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS+1];
```

and write the inside for loop as

```
for(j=0;j<MAXLETTERS;j++,turn++)
{   
    x=lcg(x);           /* random number generated */

    if(turn%2)          /* one consonant, one vowel, in turn */
        words[i][j]=consonants[x%19];
    else
        words[i][j]=vowels[x%5];
}
words[i][MAXLETTERS] = '\0';
```

Comment: Your method 1 scares the willies out of me but it is correct. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

There is no room in the array for the string terminator. Consequently writing the `'\0'` terminator is undefined behaviour. In practice (since a 2D array is contiguous), the terminator was written to the next string, which was then overwritten by its data.

Try changing

```
char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS];
```

to

```
char words[MAXWORDS][MAXLETTERS+1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Also,

Watch out for `int` overflow.

Code does not insure `0 <= Xcur <= (INT_MAX - C)/A`, so `A * Xcur + C` results can then exceed `INT_MAX`...

```
int A = 445, C = 700001, M = 2097152;
int Xnext = (A * Xcur + C) % M;
```

... resulting in UB: likely negative values can then return from the function.

```
x=lcg(x);
words[i][j]=consonants[x%19];
```

`x%19` results then in `-18 ... 18` leading to bad indexing.

---

Simple fix, yet does not address the root of the issue.

```
//Use %19u so the result is never < 0, unlike %19
words[i][j]=consonants[x%19u];
```

---

I would also use `unsigned` math to avoid UB of overflow and not generate negative results.

```
int lcg(int Xcur)       /*linear congruential generator*/
{
    unsigned A = 445, C = 700001, M = 2097152;
    int Xnext = (A * Xcur + C) % M;
    return Xnext;
}
```

Code also has issue with 16-bit `int`.